# Realize a MAC using a Pseudo-random function?

Tags: symmetric, mac, pseudo-random-function

Given a pseudo-random function and assuming that we do not have any other tools,
How can we construct a MAC?

I believe this can be done. Would like to know if there is more than one way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a PRF (with larger input than output), you can use it as compression function in a [Merkle-Damgård](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) structure, yielding a hash function which you can subsequently turn into a MAC with [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). Indeed, the security proof of HMAC relies on indistinguishability of the compression function from a PRF.

There are still an awful lot of details, though. And the PRF assumption is quite strong.

Comment: Just to quibble over minor points, I think NMAC makes more sense than HMAC here (since you're starting with a compression function, rather than a hash function), and I believe the requirement is that the output has to be at least as long as the PRF key (since you'd be chaining through the key input).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if $\mathsf{PRF}$ alone can be used to construct; however there is a natural way to construct $\mathsf{MAC}$ using $\mathsf{PRF}$ and $\mathsf{UHF}$. You can see the following papers for more detail:

1. [LFSR-based hashing and authentication](ftp://ftp.zedz.net/pub/mirrors/Advances%20in%20Cryptology/HTML/PDF/C94/129.PDF). In CRYPTO 1994.
2. [Bucket hashing and its application to fast message authentication](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/bucket.ps). In CRYPTO 1995.
3. [On fast and provably secure message authentication based on universal hashing](http://shoup.net/papers/macs.pdf). In CRYPTO
   1996.

I just found a very easy way to construct $\mathsf{MAC}$ from $\mathsf{PRF}$ in the [lecture](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr10/cos433/lec9new.pdf) notes of Barak. More concisely, it says that if $\{ f_k \}_{k \in \mathcal{K}}$ is a family of $\mathsf{PRF}$, then the following is a $\mathsf{MAC}$:

$$ \mathsf{SIGN}_k(x) = f_k(x) \qquad \mathsf{VERIFY}_k(x,s)=1 \text{ iff } f_k(x)=s. $$

I think this is pretty neat.

Comment: I think the exact details depend from the used definition of pseudo-random function. If you have one that allows input of any size (like a hash function and the $f_k$ used here), it is a lot easier than if you have one with fixed input size.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a keyed PRF, where the key is sufficient to turn the function into an independent PRF, you can turn it into a keyed PRP using a Luby Rackoff construct. If you got a keyed PRP, you can use it in CBC-MAC mode.